# Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null on ember-1.0.0-pre.2

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am starting with Ember and just following this [tutorial](http://trek.github.com/).  I downloaded the last source from Ember.js web and I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </head>
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
   Test
 </script>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
   App = Em.Application.create();

   App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
     templateName: 'application'
   });
   App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();


   App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    root: Em.Route.extend({
      index: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/'
      })
    })
  });

  App.initialize();
```

It seems a pretty simple example, but I fail to see these two things:

1) Why the source of ember gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
```

On line 18 of the ember code.

2) Why I keep getting this uncaught error, if I have defined the template:

```
Uncaught Error: <App.ApplicationView:ember143> - Unable to find template "application".
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the application template before handlebars.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
     Test
   </script>
   <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. Also I needed to add to source the handlebars before adding ember.  Why would I need to put the application template before handlebars though?

Comment: App.initialize() runs all of the Ember loadHooks, one of which is the bootstrap which loads all of the templates. If you call App.initialize() after the template, it should work. If you don't call it at all, it initializes automatically. [https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/loader.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/loader.js)

Comment: So you don't really have to put body tags? O_O

Comment: You don't even have to close head or body tags ;-)